# JS - технология для интерфейса с формами ввода и кнопками для запуска Linux Shell scripts

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, drupal, shell

Подходит ли Node.JS для интерфейса с формами ввода текста и кнопками, чтобы из них запускать Linux Shell scripts? Нужно выбрать технологию для создания веб-интерфейса для онлайн сервиса по биоинформатике. В веб форму нужно будет выводить идентификатор секвенции, затем по нажатию на кнопку, будет запускаться скрипт в командной оболочке Линукса для её загрузки и обработки. Ещё нужно будет вызывать Питон с вебинтерфейса. Какая технология наиболее адекватна для поставленной задачи?

Comment: Подходит, как и практически любая другая бекэнд технология.

Comment: отправляешь запрос на сервер, на сервере запрос кладётся в очередь и возвращается идентификатор задачи, опрашиваешь состояние задачи по её идентификатору, на сервере - разборщик очереди, который, когда задача выполнена, складывает куда-то её результат. тут нет смысла обсуждать "технологии" так как можно выбрать любую понравившуюся, есть смысл обсуждать подходы к решению задачи.